# Symfony2: app_dev.php allow access only to IP?

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony2 project I want the app_dev.php only be accessible by my **IP address**. Like in the **config.php** i can set an array of IP's so this file is not accessible by everyone. 
Is this also possible for the app_dev.php ?

Comment: Just be aware that it is trivial to spoof the incoming ip address. So while you can make app_dev accessible only with a given ip address, you can't effectively restrict app_dev to only your machine.  Which, I suspect, is your real goal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In app_dev.php you will find below code

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

You can set IP addresses from which you want to access here.

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('Your IP address', '127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Comment: should that be && !in_array ?

Comment: It's not a best practice. Insight (analyse by Sensio) returns : "Using PHP response functions (like header() here) is discouraged, as it bypasses the Symfony event system. Use the HttpFoundationResponse class instead." and "$_SERVER super global should not be used." See my response http://stackoverflow.com/a/34897282/3066708

Comment: @johnnyevolunium that snippet of code comes directly from symfony's official app_dev.php

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight variation on @chanchal118 's answer. 
Our sites are behind a load balancer so IPs work slightly differently. 
Hopefully will be helpful for people with similar set ups.

I'd also be interested in hearing any thoughts on security concerns if IPs were spoofed.

```
//todo this may be a security concern if someone managed to spoof their IP as one of these
$allowedIPs = array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', 'my.organisation.ip.address');

//allow app_dev.php only under these conditions (prevent for production environment) uses HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR because behind load balancer
if (
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) &&
    ( ! in_array(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], $allowedIPs) )
){
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access the development environment.');
}
```

Answer (score -8):

```
set in virtual host

/var/apache2/sites-avable

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com/main
    ServerAlias www.domain.com/main
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/main/web
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
</VirtualHost>

switch

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName domain.com/main
    ServerAlias www.domain.com/main
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/main/web
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.